# Embaralhar texto

Tags: c#, string, lista, loop, console

```
insira o código aqui[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

[embaralhar texto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdrTD.png)

Regras:
1. Sinais de pontuação são separadores de palavras, não fazem parte de palavras e então
não são embaralhados, por exemplo:

a) “bactérias.” ficou embaralhada como “bitcaaarés.”.
b) “(agência” ficou embaralhada como “(aiêgnca”.
Note que o ponto final não mudou de posição. Considere pelo menos os seguintes
caracteres especiais como sinais de pontuação/separação:
• '\r'
• '\n'
• ' '
• ','
• '.'
• '?'
• '"'
• '\''
• '!'
• '“'
• '”'
• ':'
• '('
• ')'
• '['
• ']'
• '{'
• '}'
• '—'
• '-'
2. Palavras com 2 ou 3 letras não são embaralhadas:
a) “Vox” continua como “Vox”.
b) “os” continua como “os”.
3. Quando uma palavra é embaralhada, a primeira e a última letra não podem mudar de
posição.
a) “calma” ficou embaralhada como “cmala”.
b) “fungos” ficou embaralhada como “fonugs”.

Comment: e qual a sua duvida?

Comment: Tudo kk, sou iniciante nesta linguagem

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues Primeiro passo: clique em [edit] e formate sua pergunta. Caso precise de um guia de formatação, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Falta verificar se a palavra tem menos que 3 letras, mas parace estar aqui o mais importante:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    char[] especiais = { '\r', '.', '?' };

    string palavra = "bactérias.";

    char? especial = null;

    // caso a palavra termine com um caractere especial
    if (especiais.Contains(palavra.Last()))
    {
        // guarda o caractere especial
        especial = palavra.Last();

        // remove o caretere especial
        palavra = palavra.Substring(0, palavra.Length - 1);
    }

    // Skip(1)                   : salta o primeiro elemento
    // Take(palavra.Length - 2)  : trás os elementos consuante o tamanho da palavra menos 2
    // OrderBy(c => rnd.Next())  : faz uma ordenação aleatória dos elementos
    // ToArray()                 : converte para array
    char[] chars_do_meio = palavra.Skip(1).Take(palavra.Length - 2).OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

    // new string(chars_do_meio): cria uma string a partir de um array de chars
    string resultado = $"{palavra.First()}{new string(chars_do_meio)}{palavra.Last()}{especial}";

    Console.WriteLine(resultado);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

veja funcionando em [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwCICC)